# The touchpad on my Thinkpad (T420) no longer works in 14.04. Why?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, touchpad, thinkpad

The Fn+F8 keyboard shortcut which used to toggle between the touchpad, legendary thinkpad red pointing device button thingy in the middle of the keyboard, and both, no longer does anything apart from show up an image of the touchpad with a X to signify that the touchpad is turned off, no matter how many times I press it. There now seems no way to toggle the the touchpad on or red pointer off and I'm stuck having to use the red button pointer only which fortunately is how I've always had things set up.

Probably unrelated: Bluetooth has stopped working too in 14.04, as described in a separate question. The failing of several functions of my laptop is encouraging me to look for a different linux flavour which would be a shame as I've used it since 8.08 and held out buying a tablet until an ubuntu one comes along.